# Android Studio does not find usage of some methods and fields

Tags: android-studio

When I try to find usages (Alt F7 or Mouse-Click with CTRL-Button down on the method name at the declaration) of a Java method or field in Android Studio (Version 3.5.3) I am often receiving the message "No usages found in all places" although the method/field is definitely used - often even in the same class.
Is there some kind of index which needs to be updated?
Or any other idea, why obviously existing usages are sometimes not found.

Answer (score 6):

Found it: There is a menu entry "File->Invalidate Caches/Restart ...".
After trying that, everything worked fine again.
Hope this helps others when running into the same problem.

BTW: Pretty dangerous if one relies on the wrong usage information and starts to delete unused methods...

Comment: Must be reported to Android Studio dev team :)